# Unable to SSH to a server from Jenkins using ED25519

Tags: ssh, openssl, key-authentication

RSA keys going to be decommissioned due to weak security and hence tried o generate a key using ED25519 type using the command

```shell
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C “testkey”
```

and generated the public private key. Copied the public key to the `authorized_key` folder of the remote server and tried to hit the server from jumphost using private key which is successful but the same is not working when tried from Jenkins.

- Command used to SSH

  ```shell
  ssh -i “ed25519 private key with proper permission” user@remotehost “pwd”
  ```
- `ssh -V` is returning the same versions across jumphost server, Jenkins server and remote server
- `ssh -Q key` is returning `ed25519` across same three servers

Not sure where exactly the issue and why alone Jenkins is not able to connect and giving authentication failed.

- Tried `ssh -vvv` to check the logs in verbose and getting same authentication failed errors with not much information.
- `sshd` config also looks to be fine as well as firewall is open.
- Tried to convert the key to PEM format but not working again -

  ```shell
  ssh-keygen -p -m PEM -f
  ```

  but no luck and it is still in OpenSSh format.
- `OpenSSL pkcs8 -in -topk8 outform PEM -out path` and no luck

Not sure of the root cause of this issue that Jenkins is failing to authenticate to that server.

Comment: Have you checked the server's sshd logs?

Comment: No I don’t have access to those logs

Comment: Then ask someone who has access to them to check

Comment: `authorized_keys` (not `_key`) is a file (not a folder). You say something (apparently `ssh` commandline) is successful but Jenkins fails, then you say `ssh` fails; which is it? It is impossible for ssh-keygen to convert an ed25519 key to 'PEM' format (really OpenSSL legacy) because that doesn't exist; the PKCS8 format exists but ssh-keygen (as of today) can't write it. Maybe you should try an ecdsa key instead; that _can_ be converted to (or generated in the first place as) PEM or PKCS8.

Comment: Could you post the output you get, when you use the ssh -vvv command? Please render IP addresses away, but leave key fingerprints for further analysis.

Comment: Thanks Dave yes it is authorized key file. I mean to say that connecting to remote server using jumphost or jump server or bastion host is successful using Ed25519 private key but same when I tried to connect to remote server from Jenkins server using ed25519 same private key is failing though there are no firewall or config issues and all of the servers are RHEL 7

Comment: Thanks Kalle output of -vvv does not have fingerprints in the output getting error like receive packet type 50 or 51 and identity file type -1.

Comment: One more input wanted to share that earlier I was using rsa public private key and that rsa public key is still present in remote authorized key file plus newly created ed25519 public key, will it create a issue if we have two different type of public key in authorised key file and from the source Jenkins already tried in the past with rsa private keys.

Comment: so my understanding is it will get added in the know host file and now if I try to access that remote server with ed25519 private key is giving a error I believe and remote expects rsa private key. please correct me if I am wrong and let me know if I need to remove the rsa public key from remote server